# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException with multiple http sections in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm writing a RESTful web service that requires multiple authentication mechanisms (basic, x509, and anonymous).  I therefore have three `<http>` elements in three separate spring context files.

When I start my service, I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain] 
is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: 
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2
```

I think this makes sense, right?  I've defined three <http> elements, so spring is probably creating three instances of org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.  And now someone is asking for a bean of type org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain, and is finding three.

But, [according to Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity), this is supposed to be possible, so my question is: How do I get this scenario to work?

Here are my three `<http>` configurations:

x509Auth.xml:

```
<sec:http pattern="/service/x509/**" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:x509 subject-principal-regex="(.*)" user-service-ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/service/x509/identity/**" access="hasRole('Domain Users')" />
</sec:http>
```

basicAuth.xml:

```
<sec:http pattern="/anubis/basic/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/service/basic/identity/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:http-basic />
</sec:http>
```

noAuth.xml:

```
<sec:http pattern="/service/anonymous/**" security="none" />
```

Comment: I don't remember offhand how to configure this (I never got my head really around the Spring Security namespace), but the `sec:http` stanza implicitly creates a Spring bean. Having multiple copies registers multiple beans, as you see. Can you link to the docs that suggest this is workable?

Comment: @chrylis I've edited my post to include a link to the section of documentation that says it's possible.

Comment: I'm quite sure that each of those configurations are valid by itself. The problem must be how it's all wired together. There should only be a single filter chain even if you have different authentication mechanisms for different URLs.

Comment: can you confirm the spring-security version you are using ?

Comment: can you try adding all http elements in one context file, instead of multiple ?

Comment: @coder Yes, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this InfoQ post](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/12/spring-security-3.1), I learned that with new flexibility comes new responsibility.  Since you can have multiple `<http>` elements now, you can also have multiple authentication managers.  This requires us to tell spring which authentication manager goes with each`<http>` element.

Here is my now-working spring configuration:

```xml
<!-- This section configures X509 Certificate Authentication -->
<sec:http
        pattern="/service/x509/**"
        use-expressions="true"
        authentication-manager-ref="ldapAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:x509 subject-principal-regex="(.*)" user-service-ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/service/x509/identity/**" access="hasRole('Domain Users')" />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="ldapAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="ldapUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- This section configures BASIC Authentication -->
<sec:http
        pattern="/service/basic/**"
        use-expressions="true"
        create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="mongoAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:http-basic />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/service/basic/identity/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="mongoAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="mongoUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- This section configures NO Authentication -->
<sec:http pattern="/service/anonymous/**" security="none" />
```